# Sendkey command not funtional on password editbox when automating Yahoo mail login

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, passwords, yahoo-mail

I am new to selenium web driver. I tried to automate login to yahoo mail using Selenium java on eclipse IDE. But, the send key command does not work on the password edit box.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "D:\\Jav\\msedgedriver.exe");
    WebDriver papa = new EdgeDriver();
    papa.get("https://login.yahoo.com//");
    papa.manage().window().maximize();
    
    papa.findElement(By.id("login-username")).sendKeys("adcbbb");
    papa.findElement(By.id("login-signin")).click();

    papa.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'login-passwd\']")).sendKeys("123456");
```

Why isn't this working, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you have:

```
papa.findElement(By.id("login-username")).sendKeys("adcbbb");
papa.findElement(By.id("login-signin")).click();

papa.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'login-passwd\']")).sendKeys("123456");
```

The only issue i can see as of now is that you must pass values to input fields and only than click to Sign In. So your code should be in this order:

```
papa.findElement(By.id("login-username")).sendKeys("adcbbb");
papa.findElement(By.id("login-passwd")).sendKeys("123456");

papa.findElement(By.id("login-signin")).click();
```

Also, if you have attributes: <id or <name use them first, instead of creating a XPATH